# PDO returns empty array as result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a simple search `form`, which I use to send a `POST` request to my php script using AJAX. I want the script to search my database for the keyword in the title column, and return the rows where it finds it. The posted data looks like this `"searchword=test1"`, where `test1` in the content of my text input.

I have 2 rows in my database, one has a title of test1, and another of test2. If I do `SELECT * FROM articles` I can see the results fine. If I type `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE 'test1';` into console, I get the correct result, but my php script returns an empty array.

No idea what I'm doing wrong here, any help is appreciated.

my php:

```
try {
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=topdecka_PTC",$username, $password);

    if (!empty($_POST["searchword"])) {
        $searchword = $_POST["searchword"];
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE %:seachword%");
        $query->execute(array(':searchword' => $searchword));

        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($result);
        die();
    } 
    else {
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles');
        $query->execute();

        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($result);
        die();
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: `$_POST{"searchword"}` syntax error and for all your POST arrays; *for one thing*. Read up on superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php more specifically for `$_POST`.

Comment: Use this => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: changed the curly braces into [ ], still won't work. I don't get any errors though, it just returns an empty array instead of the row in which the title column is 'test1'

Comment: you forgot the `$` in `%:seachword%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you forgot the `$` sign for `%:seachword%` as per your assignment:

Sidenote: There's a typo that I just noticed in `seachword` which should read as `searchword` as per `':searchword' => $searchword`

```
$searchword = $_POST["searchword"];
```

However, I'd do something like this instead:

```
LIKE :seachword
```

then

```
$query->execute(array(":searchword" => "%" . $searchword . "%"));
```

Example syntax:

```
$sqlprep = $conn->prepare("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE :word");
$sqlprep->bindValue(':word', '%value%');
```

---

Also make sure that your form does have a POST method and that your element is indeed named and no typos.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, to catch potential errors, if any.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. First of all, I had to set my form method to post. After that I used your concatenation in the $query->execute statement, and removed the % signs from the $db->prepare SQL syntax, and now it works. Now to move on to input validation =)

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič You're quite welcome, and I'm glad to hear it Miha. I usually add a note about making sure that the form is indeed explicitly implying a POST method, as forms default to GET if the method is omitted, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because the value for :searchname is being escaped.  As a result,

`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE %:seachword%`

is being interpreted as this:

`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE %"test1"%`

which is an invalid query.  You need to quote the entire string or use concat() to add the % in.

Your two options are:

`$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :seachword");
$query->execute(array(':searchword' => "%" . $searchword . "%"));`

or:

`$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :seachword, '%')");
$query->execute(array(':searchword' => $searchword));`

Personally, I prefer the option with CONCAT as it separates responsibilities better, in my opinion.